# Settings keep crashing when I try to open them through my notifications in my android app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, foreground-service, foregroundnotification

I am trying to create a service in my android app. This service further starts a foreground service. I am trying to make sure that when i click this notification of this foreground service I am taken to channel settings of this notfication(where user can easily disable the notfications for this channel).But this isn't happening. Instead when I click the settings gets crashed. Where am I going wrong? This is the code which I have used:

```
public class AlarmHandlerService extends Service {

        public NotificationCompat.Builder createNotification(String title, String content, String channel_id, int priority) {

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), channel_id)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(content)
            .setPriority(priority);
    return builder;
}

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Intent i = new Intent(Settings
                .ACTION_CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS)
                .putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, AlarmHandlerService.class)
                .putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_CHANNEL_ID, "foreground_services")
                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this,
                1,
                i,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );

        startForeground(1, createNotification("Foreground Service", "Click here to disable this foreground service", "foreground_services", NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT).setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build());

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

EDIT:
Figured out the solution...as correctly pointed by @snachmsm I had set up my intent in the wrong way...This should be the correct code for the intent..

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS);
    intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, getPackageName());
    intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_CHANNEL_ID, "foreground_services");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this,
            1,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );
```

Comment: When your app crashes, post a stacktrace. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - https://developer.android.com/studio/debug

Answer (score 0):

you are creating `Intent` with `Service` (assuming by name of `AlarmHandlerService.class`), then you are using it for creating `PendingIntent` with `getActivity` method. it should be `getService` method

btw. this is called "notification trampoline" (running non-UI `Context` after notification click) and is forbidden on newest (currenlty) Anroid 12. [some article about](https://proandroiddev.com/notification-trampoline-restrictions-android12-7d2a8b15bbe2)

Comment: Yes if I do this the app doesn't crash but I am not getting navigated to settings of that channel

Comment: you should create `NotificationChannel` like in [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels#CreateChannel) and then you know channel ID (you are setting it). and in [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels#UpdateChannel) you can check how this `Intent` should be created - you aren't passing proper `packageName`, instead some `*.class`